# Как правильно написать - объяснительная или заявление?

Tags: общие

Как правильно написать - объяснительная или заявление?

Comment: @Николай ЖЖ, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Какова Ваша цель в данном документе?

Answer (score 2):

*Объяснительная записка* - в случае, если от вас на законном основании требуют объяснения ваших действий в письменном виде.

*Заявление* - если в результате написанного вы рассчитываете на действия со стороны организации (принятие на работу, выплату денег, расследование происшествия и т. п.).